# How to create a function that multiplies all numbers between 1 and "x" with dotimes?

Tags: scheme, racket

I'm making a function that multiplies all numbers between an 1 input and a "x" input with dotimes loop. If you please, check my function and say what's wrong since I don't know loops very well in Scheme.

```
(define (product x)
  (let ((result 1))
        (dotimes (temp x)
                 (set! result (* temp (+ result 1))))
    result))
```

Comment: Scheme doesn't have `dotimes` (which, IIRC, is a Common Lisp thing).

Comment: I learn scheme with dotimes, and I can construct dotimes cicles, in racket (plt-scheme)

Comment: Um, you just asked [almost the same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6311057/scheme-how-to-create-a-function-that-multiplies-all-numbers-between-a-and-b).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use recursion. It is the way to do things in Scheme/Racket. And try to never use `set!` and other functions that change variables unless there really is no other choice.

Here's a textbook example of recursion in Scheme:

```
(define factorial
  (lambda (x)
    (if (<= x 1)
        1
        (* x (factorial (- x 1))))))
```

Comment: I agree. If you are using set! early in your Scheme/Racket career you are defeating the purpose and more importantly, missing the point.